# Obj-C MD5 Hash not matching Java / SQL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hash, character-encoding, md5

I'm trying to take a unicode string, pass it through an MD5 hash function, and encode the result as Base64.  I need MSSQL, Java and Obj-C to all return the same result.  I have MSSQL and Java agreeing, but I cannot get the same result using Obj-C.

#### Java code (returns "SC0RfYWqWLK/YNpIDdGi8w==")

```
String input = "chinese lorem ipsum 槏殟殠巘斖蘱飣偓啅撱簻臗";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
md.update(input.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
byte[] enc = md.digest();
String md5Sum = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
System.out.println(md5Sum);
```

#### MSSQL code (returns "SC0RfYWqWLK/YNpIDdGi8w==")

```
DECLARE @Str nvarchar(200)
SET @Str = N'chinese lorem ipsum 槏殟殠巘斖蘱飣偓啅撱簻臗'
DECLARE @Bin varbinary(max)
SET @Bin = HashBytes('MD5', @Str);
DECLARE @Hash char(24)
SET @Hash = CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@Bin"))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
PRINT @Hash
```

#### Obj-C code (returns "vZRPxuE84whftlx697i/Ig==")

```
NSString *input = @"chinese lorem ipsum 槏殟殠巘斖蘱飣偓啅撱簻臗";
NSData *data = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
NSData *hashData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:digest length: sizeof digest];
NSString *base64 = [hashData base64EncodedString];
NSLog(@"%@", base64);
```

Please could you help me get Obj-C to return the same value as the others.  It will be running in iOS app.  Thanks.

Comment: Not an expert here, but just a guess - have you tried using `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding` encoding for initialising data from string?

Comment: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding works! Thank you. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: You don't. It was a comment. I will post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not an expert here, but just a guess - have you tried using NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding encoding for initialising data from string?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem may be that Java and MSSQL do not add a byte order mark to the beginning of the string, while dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion: with NSUnicodeStringEncoding does.

You can verify this by checking the size (and maybe even the actual content, if this turns out not to be the problem) of the actual UTF-16 data in java and objective-c.

Comment: AFAIK NSUnicodeStringEncoding uses UTF-16 LE. But it may very well be the case that NSUnicodeStringEncoding does prepend the marker while NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding does not prepend it. It should not be hard to verify if the byte order marker is the problem or not and, if it is, whether using NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding gets rid of it or you still need to remove it manually.